# Are there alternative 2-d rings to the complex ring?

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers

By this I mean a 2-dimensional (plane) ring not based on the usual addition and multiplication, and not something that is isomorphic to the complex ring. And also not a ring that is based on a lower dimensional subset (such as the unit circle). Perhaps based on an operation that uses elliptic curves.

Comment: Dimension theory is an important facet in commutative algebra. I believe the answer to your question is yes, there are a great many rings such rings, but they will have 'addition' and 'multiplication' or some form or another. Perhaps if you said a few more words about your question, I could say a little more.

Comment: There is also the question of '2D over what?' It seems you're thinking of the complex numbers over the real numbers. That's fine, but it is a particular kind of interpretation. The complex numbers are one dimensional over themselves, and I feel like usually elliptic curves are thought of over an algebraically closed field - in which case we'd be talking about elliptic curves over C.

Comment: Yes, 2D over the reals. Also I was thinking of elliptic curves in 2D (x and y both real) rather than as complex solutions (x and y both complex) to the elliptic equation.

Comment: You might start with something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension

The Krull dimension can be seen to coincide in a great many cases with your usual notion of dimension when you think about algebraic varieties.

Comment: I have a feeling you aren't clearly thinking about what dimension you are talking about.  A dimension lower than $2$ would be $1$ or $0$.Algebraically, something $1$ dimensional over $\mathbb R$ is equal to $\mathbb R$, and the only thing $0$ dimensional over $\mathbb R$ is $\{0\}$. So, it raises the question of what dimension you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is along the lines you wanted to go, but *every* division ring is the coordinate ring for a $2$-dimensional geometry.